# Is there a cleaner way to use a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a 2D array class, and ran into a problem. The best way I could figure out to do it was to pass get/setitem a tuple of the indices, and have it unpacked in the function. Unfortunately though, the implementation looks really messy:

```
class DDArray:
    data = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]

    def __getitem__ (self, index):
        return (self.data [index [0]], self.data [index [1]])

    def __setitem__ (self, index, value):
        self.data [index [0]] = value
        self.data [index [1]] = value

test = DDArray ()

print (test [(1,2)])

test [(1, 2)] = 120

print (test [1, 2])
```

I tried just having it accept more parameters:

```
class DDArray:
    data = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]

    def __getitem__ (self, index1, index2):
        return (self.data [index1], self.data [index2])

    def __setitem__ (self, index1, index2, value):
        self.data [index1] = value
        self.data [index2] = value

test = DDArray ()

print (test [1, 2])

test [1, 2] = 120

print (test [1, 2])
```

but that results in a weird type error telling me that I'm not passing enough arguments (I guess anything inside of the subscript operator is considered 1 argument, even if there's a comma).

(Yes, I know,  the above class isn't actually a 2D array. I wanted to have the operators figured out before I moved on to actually making it 2D.)

Is there a standard way of doing it that looks a little cleaner?
Thanks

Comment: 2d arrays are already supported natively, why do you want to write your own 2d array?

Comment: @Hari Shankar I did a quick search of the docs, and tried doing a = [] [], but that yielded a syntax error. I'll look harder into the docs. Thanks

Comment: Ah. Before it can be used, it needs to be initialized as a list of lists (a = [[]])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this. If you want syntax like `test[1][2]`, then you can have `__getitem__` returns a column (or row), which can be indexed again with `__getitem__` (or even just return a list).

However, if you want the syntax `test[1,2]`, you are on the right track, `test[1,2]` actually passes the tuple `(1,2)` to the `__getitem__` function, so you don't need to include the parantheses when calling it.

You can make the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` implementations a little less messy like so:

```
def __getitem__(self, indices):
    i, j = indices
    return (self.data[i], self.data[j])
```

with your actual implementation of `__getitem__` of course. The point being that you have split the indices tuple into appropriately named variables.

Comment: Hari actually answered my question, but not as an answer, so I'll select this because it's helped too.

Comment: Last Syntax with  "indices" and unpacking is the way to do it.