# Can __setitem__ take 4 arguments including self. Whereever I have looked it can only take 3 arguments including self

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, operator-overloading

```
    class Matrix:
  def __init__(self,row,column):
    self._matrix = [[0 for self._row in range(row)] for self._column in range(column)]
  def __len__(self):
    self._r = len(self._matrix)
    self._c = len(self._matrix[0])
    return r , c
  def __add__(self, matrix):
    if ((len(self._matrix)  != len(matrix)) or (len(self._matrix[0]) != len(matrix[0]))):
      print('Dimentions don\'t agree')
    for i in range(self._row):
      for j in range(self._column):
        self._matrix[i][j] = self._matrix[i][j] + matrix[i][j]
  def __getitem__(self, i, j):
    return self._matrix[i][j]
  def __setitem__(self, i, j, val):
    self._matrix[i][j] = val    
  def __str__(self):
    for row in self._matrix:
      self._string += (''.join([str(elem) for elem in row]))
    return self._string
if __name__ == '__main__':
    m1 = Matrix(2,3)
    m2 = Matrix(2,3)
    for i in range(2):
      for j in range(3):
        m1[i,j] = 1
    for i in range(2):
      for j in range(3):
        m2[i,j] = 2
    m1 = m1 + m2
```

I am a novice at python and reading a book to understand the concepts. I went through polymorphism and tried to implent a class which uses that concept named matrices which can create, set item, add and do some operations on the matrix object. I am not stuck as I need my setitem funtion to have 3 arguments removing self but in the book which I am following and everywhere else on the internet every one has used 2 arguments aside the self for setitem. What can I do to solve this problem?
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLXeW.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774804/setitem-implementation-in-python-for-pointx-y-class . I advise you to read the doc about `__setitem__`

Comment: I have read this answer already and this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__setitem__` takes only 3 argument : `self`, `index` and `value`.

For your code to be clearer, you need to do :

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    i, j = index
    return._matrix[i][j]

def __setitem__(self, index, value):
    i, j = index
    self._matrix[i][j] = value
```

This is the way to do what you're trying to program, with your current syntax, such as `m1[i, j]`.

There is a more documented answer that you can find [right there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896471/is-there-a-cleaner-way-to-use-a-2-dimensional-array).

Though in your code there will be more problems **not related** with your question (index out of range), I will let you solve this one alone. :)